# Django excessive queries with Inlines

Tags: mysql, django, database, performance, inline

In my `Django` model I have a class C1 that contains references to other classes as attributes. So each class has a dedicated table in the database, and each attribute of C1 is a foreign key. I define what to display on a page in `admin.py`, and for each instance of C1, I use an `Inline` to display each one of its attributes. The thing is, to load such page `Django`  produces a number of `mysql` queries that increases exponentially with the number of attributes in the class C1 that are in turn instances of other classes. And this leads to excessive waiting delays. My preoccupation is to reduce this delay in an efficient way. This question may be seen as a duplicate to this thread: [Slow performance for Django admin inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305908/slow-performance-for-django-admin-inline). However I am not sure whether the accepted solution is optimal. Since I'm a bit confused here I'll ask some naive questions:

- Is displaying many of a class's attribute a viable solution in general?
- Should I instead create other pages that display and manipulate very specific and targeted elements/attributes of the said class?
- Should I do some database-side work and understand which are the redundant queries `Django` does, in order to manually create views in my database and reduce all the `Django` queries to more simple ones? I think this would defeat one of the `Django`'s purposes of developing a website without caring about the database, but I'd do it anyway if it is required
- Anything else that will do?

Comment: I'm not sure what your questions are. You can certainly use the normal techniques for minimising database queries - eg select_related and prefetch_related - in the admin.

Comment: "Classes" and "OO" were invented long after SQL was set in concrete.  Several packages attempt, with troubles, to marry the two dissimilar concepts together.